# Is it possible to find which condition has failed in a single if/else statement with multiple conditions?

Tags: python

Very shortly I need to verify if 3 conditions are verified and if not execute something regarding the failed conditions. I know I can iterate through the 3 conditions with multiple if/else statements but I was wondering if there is a simpler and more concise way to do it.

In a more generic way:

```
   if condition1 and condition2 and condition3: pass
   else: print which condition has failed
```

For an applied case:

```
if file_exist("1.txt") and file_exist("2.txt") and file_exist("3.txt"):
         pass
else: 
         #find which condition has failed
         #for file of the failed condition
               create_file(...)
```

**I am not looking to solve the example above! My question is about a way of finding which condition is not verified in a series of conditions on a single if/else statement!**

Regards

Comment: cant you just have a function createIfDoesntExist?

Comment: If the idea is to append data why not to use open(filename, 'a+') to open and create if not?

Comment: cause my current example is just an example of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The `if` statement has only one condition, in this case that condition is `condition1 and condition2 and condition3`. It doesn't "remember" the results of sub-expressions in that expression, so unless they have side-effects you're out of luck.

Also be aware that if `condition1` is false then it doesn't evaluate `condition2` at all. So if you wanted to know which conditions (plural) failed, then `and` would be entirely the wrong tool for the job. You could instead do something like:

```
results = (condition1, condition2, condition3)
if all(results):
    pass
else:
    # look at the individual values
```

In practice, though, if you're going to "do something" for each false value when you look at the individual values, then you don't need to special-case them all being true. Just execute the same code doing nothing at each step.

I suppose that just to prove a point, you could do something peculiar to record the first failure:

```
def countem(result):
    if result:
        countem.count += 1
    return result
countem.count = 0

if countem(condition1) and countem(condition2) and countem(condition3):
    pass
else:
    print countem.count
```

Or get rid of the `if` to be a tiny bit more concise:

```
conditions = (lambda: condition1, lambda: condition2, lambda: condition3)
first_failed = sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda f: f(), conditions))
```

Of course this is not sensible code for your example, but as far as it goes, it handles the general case.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Didn't know that if the first condition is false the second is not evaluated. So, not possible at all.
I've learned a lot from you comment

Comment: @user2574761 it's called [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 5):

```
I know I can iterate through the 3 files with multiple if/else statements
```

Every time you notice a repetition like this in a programming problem, it's a pretty good sign you can use a cycle:

```
for filename in ("1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"):
    if not file_exist(filename):
        create_file(...)
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
[create_file( filename ) for filename in ("1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt") if not file_exist(filename)]
```

This is closer to the way you read it in english, but some people will frown upon it, because you're using a list comprehension to cause side-effects, instead of *actually creating a list*.

Comment: Thanks Gonçalo. Sure I can do it this way for the current example. However it doesn't answer the foundations of my question. My question is not just for this example but about if/else conditions instead. I will edit my question to be more generic.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just using an if/else solution:

```
for file_name in('1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt'):
    try:
       with open(file_name): # default mode 'r' to read file
           #do something... or not
    except IOError:
       with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
           #something to do...

#modes can be 'w', 'a', 'w+', 'a+' for writing, appending,write/read, append/read respectively. There are others...
```

There is also:

```
import os.path

file_path = '/this path if all files/ have the same path.../'

for file_name in('1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt'):
    if os.path.exists(file_path/file_name):
        continue
    else:
        #create the file


# though os.path.exists this will return True for directories also
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to say it looks like a for loop to meet certain conditions.

try putting in print statements to see if each condition is being met...simple but effective.