# Finding failed condition from an if statement (which has multiple condition of AND type) in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am struggling with some research with the if statements in Java. It goes something like this. Suppose there are multiple conditions inside an if statement joined with AND operator, and the condition fails due to failure of one of the condition. However it is difficult to find which condition failed due to which the whole scenario got failed. I would like to know if there is some operation or logic from which we can identify the condition that caused the failure.

NOTE: Nested if can be done, but it is not that feasible, so would like to get some input from the community. Thanks in advance.

```
if (!(employee.validateemployee(employee) && employee.Validateweb(message))) {  

    log.info(" Mandatory Validation Failed !!");
    validationHelper.DBinsert(exchange, message);                                   
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to find which condition has failed in a single if/else statement with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689678/is-it-possible-to-find-which-condition-has-failed-in-a-single-if-else-statement)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689678/is-it-possible-to-find-which-condition-has-failed-in-a-single-if-else-statement

Comment: Alternative: If you have not already considered it, take a look at using validation library - for example the one provided by [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/validator/). That may encapsulate logic you would otherwise have to write for yourself. Not just performing the field validations themselves, but collecting all the failures in a structured way.

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but if you realy need the index of the failed condition, you could do something like below with streams:

```
Stream<Boolean> myBools = Stream.of(true,false,true,true);           
int failedAt = myBools.takeWhile(Boolean::booleanValue).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() + 1;
System.out.println("Failed at position " + failedAt);
```

In your case

```
if (!(employee.validateemployee(employee) && employee.Validateweb(message))) {  
   int failedAt = Stream.of(employee.validateemployee(employee), employee.Validateweb(message))
                        .takeWhile(Boolean::booleanValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .size() + 1;
   log.info(" Mandatory Validation Failed !! at position: " + failedAt );
   validationHelper.DBinsert(exchange, message);                                   
}
```

Comment: I faced again a problem with this approach @Eritrean. Using this approach shows an error. It states that takeWhile can't be used in this location. can you please help me out ?

Comment: I also got to know that takeWhile is a usage of Java 9 and here I am in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If it is important to your code to know in

```
  if (A && B) …
```

whether A or B is false (or both) then the easy way is to not write it like that.  Write something like this instead:

```
  if (!A) …   
  else if (!B) …  
  else // A and B are true
```

If you have a lot of code for the !A and !B cases, too much to replicate, then abstract it away into a method you can call from both places.

Alternatively, in some cases you might like to write:

```
 if (A && B) … expected …  
 else if (A) … B was false …  
 else … A was false …
```

An approach I don't like in general but which is sometimes the easiest solution (say if computing A twice is expensive):

```
boolean tmp;
if ((tmp = A) && B) …  
else if (tmp) … B was false …  
else … A was false …
```

Lastly of course there's always

```
boolean isA = A;
if (isA && B) …  
else if (isA) … B was false …  
else … A was false …
```

tldr; if you need to keep knowledge of A and B separate then you have to do so in some explicit way.

Comment: Thanks for the Input ! But what if I have some more conditions to check , It is quite complex to perform an operation in this manner. I do understand that this is the best possible way to get rid of solution for now, but what if we can use Reflection API here. Any suggestions on this please ?

Comment: Suggestion on trying to solve a simple programming problem with reflection: don't.  This is a matter where the right approach is to carefully lay out the sequence of source code.  I recommend the first example I gave, which is to treat the "negative cases" (typically error conditions) one-by-one.  It's clear, it's maintainable., it's not tricky.